# Typo3 6.x : How to show Icon (pdf, jpg,...) in my Downloadlist (content type filelinks)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

does anybody know, how I can show the fileicon in my Downloadlist created with content Type filelinks in Typo3 6.1.5?
In older Typo Versions, I used the extension css_filelinks, but it doesn't work anymore.

My current Typoscript Setup:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj = COA
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.data = file:current:title //file:current:description // file:current:name
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to let TYPO3 display file icons from the filelinks content element, you need to choose any other CE layout (in the Appearance tab) than the default.

Now TYPO3 prepends the files with icons. You might not find them too beautiful. If so, you can configure the file path end type of the icons with TypoScript:

```
# path to the folder containing the icons
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.file.import = fileadmin/folder/to/my/icons/
# wrap to indicate the file type of the icons (defaults to |.gif)
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.file.wrap = |.png
```

If you want to display icons globally without setting the layout, get rid of the corresponding if statement:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.stdWrap.if >
```

Of course you could also just use CSS selectors to display the right icon:

```
a[href $='.pdf'] { background: url('icons/pdf.png') no-repeat 1px 2px; padding-left: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there no CSS-Class you can use?

Like this:

```
span.csc-uploads-fileName {
    background: url("../img/icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 40px;
    width: 43px;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
```